# Is it possible to use a conditional validation rule as a custom formula in validation box in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: validation, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I would like to set a validation in Column D (please see the published spreadsheet at the link below [1]) in such a way that it only shows the items of either column A (A3:A) or B (B3:B) (but not all the items of both columns together) **depending upon the Service which is put in Col. C**.

So, if somebody put "Typing Services" in C3, the cell D3 has a validation having all the items of **column A (A3:A) only**. And similarly, if somebody put "Translation Services" in C3, the cell D3 has a validation having all the items of **column B (B3:B) only**.

I believe a custom formula in validation box in column D can do it. However, i am unable to produce it.

Thank you for your solution!

[1]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XdcKbxKvIOSFK37zwULZns6giE9ounHPS5iHrRFkvIk/edit#gid=697587372 [1]

Comment: I think this will require a custom script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want. Add this to your script editor:

```
 function onEdit(event){
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
 var s=ss.getSheetByName("custom formula in validation")
 var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
 var lr=event.source.getActiveSheet().getLastRow()
 var editedCell = event.range.getSheet().getActiveCell();
 var editVal=event.range.getSheet().getActiveCell().getValue()
 var editRow=event.range.getSheet().getActiveCell().getRow()

 if(sheet=="custom formula in validation" && editedCell.getColumn() ==3){
   if(editVal=="Typing Services"){
     var validation=s.getRange(3, 1, lr,1)
     var cell= s.getRange(editRow,4,1,1)
     var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validation).build();
     cell.setDataValidation(rule);
   }
      if(editVal=="Translation Services"){
       var validation=s.getRange(3, 2, lr,1)
       var cell= s.getRange(editRow,4,1,1)
       var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validation).build();
cell.setDataValidation(rule);
 }}}
```

This is a share of my test spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10lQnZ3m6wJYAC29ylZEM1Yj2vCzKljcE9zGZNn-bRiQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: That is ingenious. :) Thank you very much, Ed!

Comment: Hi @Ed 1 more query if u don't mind... what part of script need to be edited and how if the source data is in different sheet  i.e., if column A and B are in another sheet than the currently they are in the example spreadsheet the link of which i gave above. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Hi @EdNelson 1 more query if u don't mind... what part of script need to be edited and how if the source data is in different sheet i.e., if column A and B are in another sheet than the currently they are in the example spreadsheet the link of which i gave above. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: It is not clear if you mean another sheet in the same spreadsheet or in another spreadsheet. If it is in the same spreadsheet use query to bring in columns A&B. If it is another spreadsheet use importrange. Both are formulas and require no script changes.

Comment: Sorry, i was not clear enough! The source/reference data (that is, data in column A and B in the above sheet) is in another sheet (named "custom formula in validation 2") whereas the columns (column C and D), where the entries need to be done, are in the same sheet (named "custom formula in validation") as before. Copying the data from one sheet to another sheet is not feasible because it will make the spreadsheet go beyond its cell-limit.

Comment: I changed the shared spreadsheet with the needed changes for a new sheet. I noted in the script what was changed.